# How to cluster the data given a CSV file with text attributes in it?

Tags: csv, text, cluster-analysis

I've a csv file with details about the words in a document. The headings are font-size,font-name,position of the text and finally the word. I want to cluster the records in the data to see similarly formatted words.
Since there is text information for fields like font-name, I'm not able to proceed with the usual clustering techniques.

Could you please give any valuable thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: why can't you cluster font-name? it's just clustering by string equality.

Comment: Thanks alot Thomas. I wanted to get equivalent numerical representation for the strings. I got the unique strings from each column and assigned them a value. It is fine now!